# Identifying absolute phrase

Tags: present-participles

In an exercise I had to find how the participle was used in sentences.

One of the sentence was--

> The traveller, being weary, sat by the wood side to rest.

Its answer was

> ***being*** - present participle, Absolute phrase.

Why it is an absolute phrase I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

An absolute phrase is a phrase that modifies/describes a noun within the sentence but is not connected to the rest of the sentence by a conjunction.

In your example, *being wary* describes the traveler and does not use a conjunction (because, and, so, but, yet . . .).

There are two verbs in your sentence. The main verb is *sat* (to sit, past tense). The second verb is *being* (to be, present tense) and it is part of the phrase that describes the traveler, not saying what the traveler is doing.

Contrast this with:

> The traveler was weary.
>
> The traveler sat by the wood side to rest because she was weary.

In these examples, the verb *to be* is functioning as the main verb or is more strongly joined to the rest of the sentence through the conjunction *because*.

Comment: Is the same case is with The children coming home from school look in at the open door ?

Comment: @Ksh You are asking if there is an absolute phrase in the sentence "The children, coming home from school, look at the open door?" There is 